# Specification of DDNS update protocol

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns, ddns

Where can I find the protocol specifications for updating a dynamic DNS server?

In D-Link routers, there're hardcoded options for dyndns.com and no-ip.com. There's also a Manual option where the following parameters can be specified:

- Server Address
- Host Name
- User Name
- Password

What is the update protocol that uses the above parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it uses [this HTTP API](https://help.dyn.com/remote-access-api/) used by by DynDNS (which is also the same protocol that's used by [No-IP](https://www.noip.com/integrate/request) as well).

The core of the protocol consists of making an HTTP GET request to `/nic/update` at the specified server, with two query parameters (`hostname=` and `myip=`):

```
http://<SERVER>/nic/update?hostname=<HOSTNAME>&myip=<IP>
```

The username and password are sent via HTTP 'Basic' authentication.

---

The *actual* standard DNS update protocol would be [RFC 2136 "DNS UPDATE"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2136). However, most "dynamic DNS" services do not support it, and your router doesn't support it either.

Comment: I wrote a server to handle the requests, and can confirm that the D-Link router sends a GET request to `http://<Server Name>/update?hostname=<Host Name>` with User Name/Password using Basic authentication. The IP address is assumed to be the caller's. There is no option for Https.